# C++ WebSocket in macOS App

Tags: c++, objective-c, sockets

I'm trying to build a little Chat App just between the Server and the Client. I stumbled across this  [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IydkqseK6oQ&list=LLR9aJTrbYxkspCowpq82g5w&index=1) video ([GitHub source](https://github.com/hassanyf/Simple-Server-and-Chat-Program)).
If I run both scripts everything works fine but if I try to put the Client-Side into an macOS Application the Client says that it has connected even though the Server isn't running.

Client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "Client.hpp"

using namespace std;

void connectToServer()
{
    int client;
int portNum = 1600; // NOTE that the port number is same for both client and server
bool isExit = false;
int bufsize = 1024;
char buffer[bufsize];
char* ip = "127.0.0.1";

struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (client < 0)
{
    cout << "\nError establishing socket..." << endl;
    exit(1);
}


cout << "\n=> Socket client has been created..." << endl;
   server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNum);

if (connect(client,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == 0)
    cout << "=> Connection to the server port number: " << portNum << endl;

cout << "=> Awaiting confirmation from the server..." << endl; //line 40
recv(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
std::cout << client << std::endl;
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
cout << "=> Connection confirmed, you are good to go...";

cout << "\n\n=> Enter # to end the connection\n" << endl;

// Once it reaches here, the client can send a message first.

do {
    cout << "Client: ";
    do {
        cin >> buffer;
        send(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
        if (*buffer == '#') {
            send(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
            *buffer = '*';
            isExit = true;
        }
    } while (*buffer != 42);

    cout << "Server: ";
    do {
        recv(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
        cout << buffer << " ";
        if (*buffer == '#') {
            *buffer = '*';
            isExit = true;
        }

    } while (*buffer != 42);
    cout << endl;

} while (!isExit);

cout << "\n=> Connection terminated.\nGoodbye...\n";

close(client);
}
```

ViewController.mm

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

connectToServer();

}
```

Console Output:

```
=> Socket client has been created...
=> Awaiting confirmation from the server...
=> Connection confirmed, you are good to go...
=> Enter # to end the connection

Client: test *
Server: * 
Client:
```

Comment: You are under the misapprehension that a web socket is the same thing as a regular TCP connection.  Web Sockets are an extension of the HTTP protocol and must be started using HTTP.  Further, web sockets have their own framing.  See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273502/java-socket-and-js-websocket/41273633#41273633 for details.

Comment: Thanks for the Information I changed the search tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Socket and JS WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273502/java-socket-and-js-websocket)